# Ошибка сегментирования (core dumped)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
int dig[10];
int i,j,max_index,tmp,min_index;
srand (time(NULL));

for ( i = 0 ; i <= 9 ; i++){/*Заполняем случайными числами*/
   dig[i] = 0 + rand() %31;
   printf("%d ",dig[i]);
}
printf("\n");
/*Сортировка по возрастанию*/
for ( i = 9 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
   max_index = 0;
   for (j = 0 ; j <= i ; j++){
      if (dig[j] >= dig[max_index])
      max_index = j;
      tmp = dig[i];
      dig[i] = dig[max_index];
      dig[max_index] = tmp;
}
}
for (i = 0 ; i <= 9 ; i++){
printf("%d ",dig[i]);
}
printf("\n");
/*Сортировка по убыванию*/
for (i = 9 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
   min_index = 0;
   for ( j = 0 ; j <= i ; i++){
      if (dig[j] <= dig [min_index])
      min_index = j;
      tmp = dig[i];
      dig[i] = dig [min_index];
      dig[min_index] = tmp;
}   
}
for (i = 0 ; i <= 9 ; i++){
   printf("%d ",dig[i]);
}
printf("\n\n");
}
```

По возрастанию выводит,и потом пишет: "Ошибка сегментирования (core dumped)".Подскажите решение проблемы,заранее спасибо.

Comment: Запустите в отладчике и посмотрите, какая строка.

Comment: А gdb умеет и с core'ами работать. Только надо не забыть сказать системе, что 
эту core'у создать надо. (ulimit -c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В цикле по j при сортировке по убыванию вы увеличиваете не j, а i. В итоге, обращаетесь к 11-му элементу в массиве из 10 элементов.

```
/*Сортировка по убыванию*/
for (i = 9 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
   min_index = 0;
   for ( j = 0 ; j <= i ; i++){ // j++, а не i++
     if (dig[j] <= dig [min_index])
         min_index = j;
     tmp = dig[i];
     dig[i] = dig [min_index];
     dig[min_index] = tmp;
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Учитесь пользоваться отладчиком, даже самые примитивные сильно облегчают жизнь и резко сокращают время на поиск простых ответов на простые вопросы:

[image]